# JFreeChart selectively render lines

Tags: jfreechart

Please see the the xy/timeseries chart I have posted here: http://imagebin.org/151195

How do I selectively render only the horizontal lines, and leave out the lines between the neighboring data points that don't have the same *y* value?  Basically the result would be a series of horizontal lines?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to scan your data model to find the ordinate where *dy/dx* < *ɛ*, for some value of ɛ near zero. Of course, you'll have to scan past the initial flat part, and decide how to deal with a series that never rises above ɛ.

Once you know the desired ordinate, use [`setLowerBound()`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/axis/ValueAxis.html#setLowerBound%28double%29) on your domain axis.